# Timeout not being honoured in connection string

Tags: sql-server, database, timeout

I have a long running SQL statement that I want to run, and no matter what I put in the "timeout=" clause of my connection string, it always seems to end after 30 seconds.

I'm just using `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute it, and letting it take care of opening connections, etc.

Is there something else that could be overriding my timeout, or causing sql server to ignore it? I have run profiler over the query, and the trace doesn't look any different when I run it in management studio, versus in my code.

Management studio completes the query in roughly a minute, but even with a timeout set to 300, or 30000, my code still times out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What are you using to set the timeout in your connection string? From memory that's "ConnectionTimeout" and only affects the time it takes to actually *connect* to the server.

Each individual command has a separate "CommandTimeout" which would be what you're looking for. Not sure how SqlHelper implements that though.

Comment: So obvious! But that didn't stop me from wasting two hours missing the answer....  Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that it **can't** be set up using connstring? We're using EF now and have no commands to DB that way.

Answer (score 16):

<s>In addition to timeout in connection string,</s> try using the timeout property of the SQL command. Below is a C# sample, using the SqlCommand class. Its equivalent should be applicable to what you are using.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, _Database.Connection);
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```