# To increase the timeout period

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I have to increase timeout period.Following is my code.

```
Private Function GetConnectionInstance() As SqlConnection
    Dim objConn As SqlConnection
    Dim strConnection As String
    strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("conn")

    Try
        objConn = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Return objConn
End Function
```

What code i have to add in above to increase timeout period.

Comment: Also instead of Try/Catch use Using. It will close you connection if in both cases: an exception or after your code ends

Comment: Do you mean the timeout for connecting to the database or the timeout for executing each query?

Comment: @abatishchev, while using 'using' is usually a good recommendation, in this case it would not work since the SqlConnection object is returned out from the method.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the next item into your connection string:

> Connection Timeout=30;

If you need to change Timeout only for target connection, not in the whole application, do next:

```
Dim connString as String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("conn")
Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connString)
builder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
Dim connection = New SqlConnection(builder.ToString())
```

Comment: It appears in .NET 3.5, that the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class no longer contains a Timeout property.

Comment: @eidylon: this property names is ConnectTimeout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.connecttimeout.aspx

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Try the following:</strike>

objConn.ConnectionTimeout = 600

Instead of setting it on the connection, you can set the CommandTimeout on a SqlCommand:

```
objCmd.CommandTimeout = 600
```

Comment: SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout is read-only property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx

Comment: Oy, my bad. I was thinking of SqlCommand.CommandTimeout, which is writable.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the connection string by adding "Connection Timeout = 30" to it. The default 15 and it is in seconds. However important to know is where the timeout actually occurs. You should check this topic: [Timeout not being honoured in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472/timeout-not-being-honoured-in-connection-string).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem was not actually the timeout as such, it was because the SqlConnection object was not being closed in loops.