# Timeout in LINQ to SQL inserting millions of records

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, exception, timeout

I'm inserting approximently 3 million records in a database using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727591/out-of-memory-when-creating-a-lot-of-objects-c). Eventually when the application has been inserting records for a while (my last run lasted around 4 hours), it gives a timeout with the following SqlException:

> "SqlExcepetion: Timeout expired. The timeoutperiod elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

What's the best way to handle this exception? Is there a way to prevent this from happening or should I catch the exception?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If everything you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

Seriously, even TRYING to use Linq2SQL for inserting 3 million records is a broken approach. ORM's are a lot of good things, they are NOT bulk insert elements.

I suggest:

- Generate the table data into a file
- Load the file using appropriate tools (bulk load mechanism). You wil lbe surprised about the performance (hint: I load about 600 million records in 15 minutes);)

Bulk load has a lot of performance advantages. Naturally assuming you talk of something like an ETL load process here - but I fail to see a 3 million load as anything except a data warehouse / reporting / archiving style of load operation, it definitlely and per definition is not real time transaction processing ;)

Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: I believe the expression is "If your only tool is a hammer..."

Comment: Whatever the expression is, it's an awesome explanation! +1 for this awnser, win!

Comment: In addition to TomTom's answer have a look at the SqlBulkCopy class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: In an app I am building, I am adding mere 10's of thousands of records, not millions, and linq2sql was killing me.  SqlBulkCopy made a huge different, and I was able to build it into my data layer class along side the linq2sql with no difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

Generate a SQL script (or string), and execute that directly.

L2SQL is not made for mass operations like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've to increase the CommandTimeout of your command.

Solution can be found [here](http://www.netnewsgroups.net/aspnet/t579-sqlclient-sqlexception-timeout-expired.aspx)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949374/to-increase-the-timeout-period/949381#949381