# Is it possible to change default OLEDB connection timeout value? Run-time error (80040e31)

Tags: sql-server, vba, oledb, connection-timeout

I have one legacy app (VB) and I have an issue with the timeout error while connecting to SQL Server (probably through OLEDB).

[image]

Using SQL Profiler I figure out that the connection is dropped through exactly 30 seconds.

[image]

I don't have access to the source codes but I scanned exe resources and couldn't find any hardcoded connection string timeout values there.

The last chance I think I have is to change the default OLEDB timeout somewhere outside the app.

**My question is: it is possible to change default OLEDB timeout value?**

---

UPDATE

I found the connection string and changed timeout to 300 but it does not help...

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=______;Password=______;Initial Catalog=________;Data Source=______;Connect Timeout=300
```

After that I tried to replace current connection string with connection strings from different providers: **ADO.NET** and **ODBC** but every time I get an timeout error after 30 seconds - checkmate.

P.S.

I'll be happy to any advice

Comment: There are a number of ways to set the timeout using ADO, however I believe that 30 seconds is a default value, so the program might not be setting a timeout at all. In this case, I do not see how you could change that in a compiled program, sorry... :(

Comment: But I beleave that this default 30 seconds value must be "hardcoded" somewhere in the system (driver settings, registry, global config files or somthing else...)

Comment: If it's a connection time-out, isn't it odd that its displayed in profiler? Could it be c command time-out or a post-connection authentication time-out?

Comment: Connection is dropped when the query that executing from app is running longer then 30 sec. Sometimes query executes less than 30 seconds and timeout does not occur, but more often, probably 10 per 1, query executes more than 30 second and app is throwing timeout exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472/timeout-not-being-honoured-in-connection-string). It is the command timeout and it must be configured from particular `command` object.

Answer (score 2):

There is property called "Connect Timeout". You can add this property to the connection string available in your application.

Below is the sample connection string with user specified timeout value:
(Note: Connect Timeout value is always in seconds)

connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=sa;Password=tiger;Connect Timeout=200"

Comment: No no no. I have no access to the source code to change the connection string. I search for alternative solution - without affectiong the source code

Answer (score 2):

Connect timeout is the limit of time to connect to the server, not to execute a command, so setting it will not help at all