# Connection Timeout in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, connection, timeout

I am running an application that loads too many data from the database, I don't have any wrong code or anything but every time I load too many data I get this exception

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding.
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Here is my code to load the data in my gridview

```
 private void toolStripCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //LoadData();
        #region Threading Begin
        //this.dgvCommision.Enabled = false;
        oProgressBar.Visible = true;
        lblProgress.Visible = true;
        oProgressBar.Value = 0;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
        new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        #endregion      

       // worker_DoWork();
        //ComputeCommission();
    }
```

This is worker_DoWork code from `worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork)`

```
 void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
       try
        {
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_elapsed);
            timer.Start();
            Invoke(new MyDelegate(ShowLabel), "Loading...");

            BACS.DateFrom = this.dtFrom.Value.ToShortDateString(); //this.dtFrom.Text;
            BACS.DateTo = this.dtTo.Value.ToShortDateString(); //this.dtTo.Text;
            BACS.BrokerAgent = BrokerXML;
            BACS.Payor = PayorXML;
            DS = BACS.GET_SP_BACS_ComputeCommission();
            ReadData(DS, this.dgvCommision);
            CheckGrid();
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            timer.Stop();
        }
       catch
       { }
    }
```

And this is how I load my sp command from `DS = BACS.GET_SP_BACS_ComputeCommission();` GET_SP_BACS_ComputeCommission is this

```
public DataSet GET_SP_BACS_ComputeCommission()
    {
        SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[4];
        sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@DATEFROM", DateFrom);
        sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@DATETO", DateTo);
        sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@BROKERAGENT", BrokerAgent);
        sqlParam[3] = new SqlParameter("@PAYOR",Payor);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        if (this.InitDataLayerObject() == true)
        {
            ds = this.ExecuteQuery("dbo.[SP_BACS_COMMISSION_COMPUTATION]", sqlParam);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Is there any solution in this? I've tried setting up my `Connection Timeout=0` I even changed it to `Connection Timeout=2500` Still it didn't worked.

Comment: what is time taken by sql server for procedure or statement ???

Comment: What is the size of data, showing the code could help in suggesting the solution

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar 12:47 is the time of completion when I execute the stored procedure .

Comment: Did you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472/timeout-not-being-honoured-in-connection-string

Comment: Is it a ASP.Net or WinForm app?

Comment: @Tarik It's WinForm app

Comment: @Adil You might be confused on my code though but I'll try to put my code in the question.

Comment: @Adil I've edited the question, hope you understand my code. LOL